# Autoregressive distributed lag (ADL) models and Dummy variables

Tags: categorical-data, logit, probit, ardl

Is it okay to use an Autoregressive Distributed Lag (ADL) model with a dummy variable as the dependent variable?

Or should I use a combination of logit/probit with an ADL model? I realize it might be problematic  to control for the lags of the dependent variable.

Please explain simply, I'm a novice at econometrics.